# Angular 2 - compiled HTML files

Tags: node.js, angular, copy

After compiling, I am copying my files to a /dist folder. Here are the commands, from my package.json

"copy:html-win": "xcopy .\*.html .\dist /y",
"copy:css-win": "xcopy .\*.css .\dist /y",
"copy:config-win": "xcopy systemjs.config.js .\dist /y",
"copy:modules-win": "xcopy .\node_modules\* .\dist\node_modules  /S /Y",

What this is doing is...It is copying everything as I want to the /dist folder, except the .html files are not being copied over, instead, I see .map files.

For eg:
list.component.html is missing.
but list.component.js.map is there

The contents of the list.component.js.map look like this:

```
{"version":3,"file":"list.component.js","sourceRoot":"","sources":["../../../app/list/list.component.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":";;;;;;;;;;AACA,qBAAkC,eAAe,CAAC,CAAA;AAClD,uBAA+C,iBAAiB,CAAC,CAAA;AAEjE,6BAA4B,gBAAgB,CAAC,CAAA;AAS7C;IAKI,2BAAoB,OAAoB,EAAU,KAAqB,EAAU,MAAc;QAA3E,YAAO,GAAP,OAAO,CAAa;QAAU,UAAK,GAAL,KAAK,CAAgB;QAAU,WAAM,GAAN,MAAM,CAAQ;IAAG,CAAC;IAEnG,oCAAQ,GAAR;QAAA,iBAGC;QAFG,IAAI,CAAC,OAAO,CAAC,gBAAgB,EAAE;aAC1B,SAAS,CAAC,UAAA,IAAI,IAAI,OAAA,KAAI,CAAC,aAAa,GAAG,IAAI,EAAzB,CAAyB,CAAC,CAAC;IACtD,CAAC;IAhBL;QAAC,gBAAS,CAAC;YACP,QAAQ,EAAE,MAAM,CAAC,EAAE;YACnB,WAAW,EAAE,0BAA0B;YACvC,SAAS,EAAE,CAAE,0BAAW,CAAE;SAC7B,CAAC;;yBAAA;IAaF,wBAAC;AAAD,CAAC,AAXD,IAWC;AAXY,yBAAiB,oBAW7B,CAAA"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: xcopy .\\app\\* .\\dist\\app /Y /S - Adding this script fixed the issue I was having. I was expecting that the copy HTML command would copy all of the HTML files into the subdirectory structure. But adding the /S command made it a cyclic copy, which xcopy doesn't allow.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! You should post an answer to this question, explaining your solution.